# How modify a lookslike in wxTextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I need simple editor. I use special symbols. 
How redefine onPaint or other way what wxTextCtrl show line.
For example:

```
My special <a> line have := differen symbol
```

How showing '< a >' in green color and symbol := show a bold '**=**' (without ':')

ideal is runing this special showing in all lines without actual cursor. Whole document without actual line.

Comment: Your post appears to be too broad to be answered here but you can always Google "syntax highlighting".

Comment: Take a look at wxStyledTextCtrl http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override painting of `wxTextCtrl` (or of any other native control for that matter), nor would you want to do it. You can define "text styles" for the regions in it however, see the "wxTextCtrl Styles" section of [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_text_ctrl.html) which should be enough for what you want to do.

And if you need more than this, [wxStyledTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html) could be helpful.

Comment: How modyfi wxTextCtrl? onPaint and whole area ot is any way to modyfy onli line?  which function in wich object is drawing one line?

Comment: Here is goog tutorial to modyfy wxPanel, how modyfy wxTextCtrl? http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/customwidgets/

Comment: Please reread the first sentence of my answer: there is no "function in which the object is drawing one line". You should change your approach instead of trying to do something in a wrong way.

Comment: which function drawing signs in wxTextCtrl?

Comment: You really won't take "no" for an answer, will you? How do you think asking the same question over and over again will result in a different answer? There is **no** function to override for drawing `wxTextCtrl`.